# Is there a way to prevent only a specific child from triggering a SIGCHLD?

Tags: perl, fork, posix, sigchld

I'm writing a [debugging utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22177949/1949769), and I want to `fork` a child while preventing that child's termination from triggering a `SIGCHLD` to its parent. I still want other children to normally cause a `SIGCHLD` upon termination.

I want to do this because I don't want the `fork` to trigger an existing `$SIG{CHLD}` handler, but I still want other children to trigger it. That is, I want to isolate my new child and I don't want it to interfere with management of existing children.

I'm wary of locally installing a custom `$SIG{CHLD}` handler since I don't think I can properly detect when I should call the original handler. For instance, if I install a local `$SIG{CHLD}` handler, then I'm guaranteed to receive a `SIGCHLD` signal once I spawn a child and have the parent `waitpid` for it to terminate. However, that `SIGCHLD` won't indicate whether or not other children have terminated as well, so I can't be sure whether to call the original handler.

I researched that a process cannot change its parent pid. I'm not sure if changing the child's process group id or session id would be useful.

Is it even possible to prevent a specific child from triggering the `SIGCHLD` on the parent? Am I forced to rely on the existing `$SIG{CHLD}` handler to Do The Right Thing when it receives the `SIGCHLD` signal for a child that it did not expect?

Although there may be a better way to implement that debugging utility (let me know if there is), I'm still wondering whether POSIX offers such fine-grained control over children, and am looking for a Perl solution to my dilemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *portably* prevent the `SIGCHLD` entirely, but if the signal handler is written properly you can prevent the waitpid from returning your debugging tool's pid by orphaning it.

```
use Signal::Mask;
sub start_background_child {
  local $Signal::Mask{CHLD} = 1;
  my $first = fork;
  croak "fork failed: $!" if not defined $first;
  if ($first) {
    waitpid $first, 0;
    return;
  }

  my $second = fork;
  croak "fork failed: $!" if not defined $second;
  exit if $second;

  your_stuff_here();
}
```

Comment: This approach may or may not prevent that initial SIGCHLD (portability issue), but if it doesn't waitpid will never return the debugging process.

Comment: As perfect as it can get! On my macbook (OS X 10.8.2), this works as desired. Also, I love your `Signal::Mask` and `Signal::Pending` modules; they made it very easy to explore the behavior on my system. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could daemonize the special child -- fork twice -- to sever the parent-child relationship. You'd still receive a `SIGCHLD` when the process was created -- I don't know if that's acceptable for you.

```
sub start_special_child {
    return if fork;     # run rest of this routine in child process
    fork && exit;       # run rest of this routine in grandchild process
                        # the  exit  here triggers SIGCHLD in the parent
    ...                 # now run your special process
    exit;               # exit here does not trigger SIGCHLD
}
```

The other approach is to keep track of the process id's of your child processes, and use `waitpid` to figure out which process(es) triggered the `SIGCHLD` handler.

```
$SIG{CHLD} = \&sigchld_handler;
$pid1 = start_child_process();
$pid2 = start_child_process();
$pid3 = start_child_process();
$pidS = start_special_child_process();

sub sigchld_handler {
    $pid = waitpid -1, WNOHANG;     # use POSIX ':sys_wait_h'
    return if $pid == $pidS;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid that initial `SIGCHLD`, so the first approach is unfortunately not acceptable for me (since it would still trigger the existing `$SIG{CHLD}` handler). The second approach would be ideal if I had control of the original `$SIG{CHLD}` handler as well as the other children. However, I'm looking for a generic solution that works regardless of the original `$SIG{CHLD}` and without knowledge of any other children. I'd also like to avoid reaping the other children (but I don't mind if the special child is reaped).

Comment: I don't usually like Perl's threads, but maybe a thread is more appropriate here than a fork.